# MVC - Encrypt ajax call parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I am using an ajax call to invoke my action method. But sending two parameters in that call. I was to secure/ encrypt those parameters while send to action method and decrypt  those values in action method.

Is it possible?

my ajax call in view -

```
var gemid = $("#Number").val();
    var PageSig= "ABC";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { gemid : gemid, PageSig: pagename },
        success: function (data) {
            Success(data, _controlName);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //console.log(' error : ' + XMLHttpRequest.message);
        }
    });
```

Action method -

```
 public string GetSigdata(string gemid, string PageSig)
{

 }
```

Now those values which i am sending in the ajax call - gemid, PageSig .. I want encrypt while sending it and decrypt it action method for security purpose.

Is it possible?

Comment: For what possible reason?

Comment: Completely possible, utterly useless.

Comment: why would you want/need to do this? It serves no practical purpose. There's no purpose to just encrypting the values - the sender (before encryption) and the receiver (after decryption) already know what they are, and there are better, well-established ways to stop the message being intercepted - i.e. use HTTPs to encrypt the whole connection. If you are already using HTTPs, then you basically have already done what's necessary.

Comment: we are not running it on HTTPS

Comment: in that case, you should run it on HTTPS, and then your issue is easily resolved in a standard way. As an extra advantage, _all_ the communication is encrypted, not just a couple of arbitrary fields, and your user probably has more trust in your website generally.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your AJAX calls through an SSL or TLS encrypted HTTPS connection it should give pretty good basic security

Comment: I am not sure from where you got the idea that the site does not run on HTTPS already. This is at best a comment, not an answer